# Restrict subversion to only allow certain functions

Tags: svn, permissions

I'm in a bit of a situation. We have our private subversion server that we use for development, but one of our government clients is requesting access to our commit logs so that they can get an up-to-date picture of what we've been doing on the system.

I don't have a problem with them reading our commit logs, but what I do have a problem with is them having access to our source code - they can't have read **or** write.

The obvious solution is to do an `svn log` ourselves and give them an export, but they want direct SVN access as they apparently have an auditing solution that will import the `svn log` command automagically.

So, is there a way I can set up access to a subversion repo and deny them access to everything except `svn log`? I don't care if I have to set up a virtualhost just for this, but it has to be done over http(s). We're also using LDAP for authentication if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/http-and-webdav/webdav-protocol, you can use svn over HTTPS and limit their allowable access methods in host config to `OPTIONS`, `PROPFIND` & `REPORT`. Haven't got a server to test now, but seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: Perfect - thanks. It's going to give them access to a few other functions, (like `svn ls`) but that's OK because they can't read or write any of the files.

Comment: Almost works perfectly, run into a problem with Apache I think. I've asked a question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/152348/